# Xcode 8 Swift3 Conversion tool

Tags: cocoapods, swift3

Everytime i run a command "pod install" in the terminal and open up my Xcode 8. The Xcode will request my previous converted framework to go thru the conversion tool again

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using prerelease version of cocoapods, you can try with adding this to the end of your pods file:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Cocoapod's [website](https://cocoapods.org/) recommends that you use prerelease - `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre` for Xcode 8